# Joining points and polygons by date in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, spatial-join, spatio-temporal-data

I am using an aerosol index, which I reduced to a daily mean for 2019:

```
var airq_19 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_AER_AI')
  .select('absorbing_aerosol_index')
  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-12-31');

var days = ee.List.sequence(1, 365);

var composites = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(days.map(function(d) {
  var filtered = airq_19.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange({
    start: d,
    field: 'day_of_year'
  }));
  return filtered.mean().set('day', d);
}));
```

I also have point data that is dated:

```
var events = ee.FeatureCollection('users/salem043/ACLED16to20Iraq');
```

To obtain the mean values in the aerosol index, I would normally use a spatial join like  this:

```
var spatialFilter = ee.Filter.intersects({
  leftField: '.geo',
  rightField: '.geo'
});

var joinAll = ee.Join.saveAll('matched').apply(events, airq_19, spatialFilter);

var outcomes = joinAll.map(function(feature){
  var joinedFeat =  ee.List(feature.get('matched'));
  var polygon = ee.Feature(ee.FeatureCollection(joinedFeat).first());
  return ee.Feature(feature.copyProperties(polygon, properties)).select(properties);
});
```

How do I adjust the functions above such that the joins match on the basis of geography AND date? Script is [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/30cbe768760116365dd474bcd129fe58)

Feb. 9th update: I reformatted my imported feature collection so I could match days based on a number 1-365 for 2019.

```
var spatialFilter = ee.Filter.and(
  ee.Filter.intersects({
    leftField: '.geo',
    rightField: '.geo'
  }),
  ee.Filter.equals({
    leftField: 'day',
    rightField: 'day'
  })
);
```

Now the join recommended below produces a new dataframe, but I am missing one more step to produce the mean aerosol index information as a variable (it's saved as a band for each feature in the new feature collection). Updated code is [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/5fabd9f471e21413e2c0212d1fbd67e4).

Comment: You can join based on time by creating a time filter, and making sure that both time fields are in epoch milliseconds. Example here in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/joins_save_all

Comment: Please provide a link to a running script.

Comment: Just added the script link above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly how you want to combine these composites with your events, but in general, you can join on multiple properties by using `ee.Filter.and()`:

```
var filter = ee.Filter.and(
  ee.Filter.intersects({
    leftField: '.geo',
    rightField: '.geo'
  }),
  ee.Filter.equals({
    leftField: 'date',
    rightField: 'date'
  })
)
```

Something like this could perhaps be an option too:

```
ee.Join.saveAll('matched')
  .apply({
    primary: events, 
    secondary: airq_19, 
    condition: ee.Filter.and(
      ee.Filter.intersects({
        leftField: '.geo',
        rightField: '.geo'
      }),
      ee.Filter.maxDifference({
        // Include airq within 24h of event
        difference: 24 * 3600 * 1000, 
        leftField: 'system:time_start',
        rightField: 'system:time_start'
      })
    )
  })
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/1afa49f61a5f9d09327f1746a1d4c80e

Comment: Thanks! I used the first (Filter.and) and was able to obtain a feature collection, but where the aerosol values are still saved as bands for each feature (point). Any tips on how to reclassify the information as a property in this feature collection? A link to my updated code is above.